# Make titles clickable for reputation/badges blocks in profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, profile-page, accessibility

On the profile's [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) there are reputation and badges blocks:

> [image: activity]

Could you please make these titles as clickable links to the corresponding tabs?

- [Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation)
- [Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=badges)

There is already link to the reputation tab from the chart, but there is no link for the badges. Using block titles as links would be intuitive, since I'm not a first time trying to click them with no effect.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. It would be useful for quickly seeing all your reputation and/or badges.

Answer (score 8):

For me here are all the links I *found* circled in red and the titles underlined in blue:

[image: activity page with Summary and Questions headers underlined in blue. Various red freehand circles are sprinkled over the page]

The text "View all 69 questions" is not only nice, but makes sense under the heading.

This breaks the UX, where previously Summary is the equivalent header and 'reputation', 'badges' and 'impact' have similar styling to the very nice 'View all 69 questions', it would be better to follow a consistent pattern.

Also, it's super unintuitive which bits of the UI should be/are clickable links (shown in freehand circles). I think that's the crux of the issue, and the OP has suggested a fix (make more things clickable) the alternative is to either make what's here clearer or make less clickable.

If I get time at work, I'll make a mock-up of what might be clearer and solve OP's problem without introducing clutter which seems to be Yaakov's concern.

---

Here is rough mockup to show something that might be a smidge clearer what's going on with links in the page:

[image: altered activity page, with links for 'view reputation table', 'view badge progress', 'view all activity' under the 'reputation', badges' and impact headers. The number reached is pulled out of the 4 item grid, and the text under each stat is styled as a link]

- Cards combined under a single 'summary' card
- Links look like links
- Headers have subheadings that use 'view' to indicate an action
- Unclickable 'reached' stat pulled out
- styling applied to the stats that are links or show popups (when not viewing own page)

Comment: I fail to see your point, sorry. OP of this question has no problem, this isn't a bug report. It is feature request asking to make sub headers into links, that's all. Something "nice to have". I agree with Yaakov it would be confusing because other sub headers won't be links, in other places. So not sure what you suggest here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I'm suggesting it's already confusing because things that look like links aren't and things that don't look like links are.

Answer (score 7):

While we're at it, let's also please make "reputation", "answers", and "questions" on the "Profile" tab clickable:

[image]

Preferably having the link for the whole div, not just the label:

[image]

Answer (score -6):

We are going to be declining this. There are already links to easily access those tabs in the profile, and we think that it can be confusing from a UX perspective to make these headers/subheaders/labels into clickable links.

Comment: I think what is or isn't a link is too confusing not to do something eventually.

Comment: It is true, there are some non-obvious links on the page, but we don't want to add to that. And none of the section or sub-section headers are links (something that this request is proposing to change).

Comment: The subheader 'View all # questions' under the 'Questions' header looks similar-enough to the 'reputation' subheader under the header 'summary' that it's confused me more than once.