# Regression in badge count design on profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

In light of more recent [design regressions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343370/new-colors-for-vote-counts-are-not-accessible-please-make-them-darker/343758#343758) I think this is one as well:

The count of badges on a profile used to look like this:

[image: courtesy of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325574/make-titles-clickable-for-reputation-badges-blocks-in-profile-page]
 <sub>Courtesy of [Make titles clickable for reputation/badges blocks in profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325574/make-titles-clickable-for-reputation-badges-blocks-in-profile-page)</sub>

Currenlty it looks like this:
[image]

It's a bit hard to see, but I believe the numbers have been bolded, which doesn't make them easier to read. I find them a bit like an out-of-focus picture, or grainy one might say.

Edit: Taking a second look to the images the words "REPUTATION" and "BADGES" are also bolded.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I doubt regression is applicable as a tag here. I don't think this bug has been previously fixed.

Comment: This isn't about badges themselves, though.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog which is why I didn't disagree on removing that ;)