# Top tag is dimmed with low contrast on activity profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I noticed the *Top tag* currently has **very low contrast** in the activity tab of the user profile - using light theme. I think this happens if you're not tracking any badge and it's likely to affect user profiles with less rep who likely don't track badges.

See the screenshot, from left to right:

1. Low contrast - not tracking any badge. (This is the bug I'm reporting.)
2. On hover - not tracking any badge.
3. Better contrast and margin - tracking badge.
4. Historical difference - how it looked in February 2020.

[image]

Screenshots 1 and 2 were taken from my profile on [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/65495). Screenshot 3 is from [Franck Dernoncourt](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/903)'s profile, the older screenshot 4 was taken from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343878).

Using Windows 10, Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2021.11.11.40730.